# Run function only on elements of list that are not none

Tags: python

Say I have a list in python: a = [1,2,3,4,None]. Suppose I want to run sklearn.preprocessing.scale on only the elements that are not equal to None. Runnig this function directly on the list gives an error message.

Is there a way to do this, without having to do it manually? I want functionality similar to the .fillna() method in pandas, where you can run a function on a dataframe that ignores the none-null elements, and then replaces them later. Thanks.

Comment: Why not filter the list and then run the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()`, but it seems like a `for` loop should work:

```
for i in a:
    if i is not None:
        #your code here#
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `sklearn`, chances are you might want to work with numpy arrays rather than Python lists:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, None], dtype=float)
>>> ix = ~np.isnan(x)
>>> x[ix] = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(x[ix])
>>> x
array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079,         nan])
```

Comment: Thanks; that is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = sklearn.preprocessing.scale( filter(None,a) )
```

should do exactly what you are asking  (well filters out any falsey value)

*note that this is only going to work for a 1d list*

I guess if you want the original list back with the scalars and nones

```
 r = iter(result) #result from above
 my_new_a = [None if  not v else next(r) for v in a]
```

Comment: But won't filter also delete the empty elements of the list? I want to keep them there in their original positions.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I almost put something like that but thought surely that cant be what OP wants. ..

Comment: `sklearn.preprocessing.scale` operates on the array as a whole. It is meaningless to apply it to the individual elements.